# Does copy-constructor or constructor work when we do copy initialization

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ExClass
{
    int data;
    ExClass(const ExClass&);

public:
    ExClass() : data(0) {}
    ExClass(int d) : data(d) { cout<<"Constructor"<<endl; }
};

int main()
{
    ExClass var(2);
    ExClass var2=2;

    return 0;
}
```

To test whether it calls copy-constructor or constructor when I use copy-initialization, I made copy-constructor private. Although it works with visual c++ 2005, codeblocks 13.12 (compiling with C++11 standards) gives an error.

When I run it as it is, it gives:

```
Constructor 

Constructor
```

as an input.

**Am I correct** thinking that it means `var(2)` and `var2=2` have the same meaning and **they both call the same constructor?**

If it is, **why** codeblocks gives an error? Since it doesn't use copy-constructor, it should not give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
ExClass var2=2;
```

...is equivalent to this...

```
ExClass var2 = ExClass(2);
```

...which nominally invokes the copy-constructor, but the Standard has a special provision allowing for this to be elided into direct construction of `var2`.  That's an *optional* optimisation the compiler can choose to perform - only *if* the compiler doesn't elide will the missing definition for the copy constructor matter.  Either way though, a the compiler must check that a copy-construction would be a legal operation (e.g. it's not deleted).

So, both compilers are right, and indeed the same compiler may get an error or not depending on the command-line optimisation flags it's invoked with.

Answer (score 1):

`ExClass var2 = 2;`

converts `2` to an `ExClass` temporary (prvalue), then initializes `var2` with that prvalue. This second step involves either a move- or a copy-constructor (typically). The call to that copy/move constructor can be elided, but it has to be possible/valid. (If the call is elided, the copy/move ctor is not odr-used and therefore no definition is required.)

The Standardese can be found in [dcl.init]/17 and [class.copy]/31ff